# How do I customize the post page

Tags: posts, pages, page-template

I'm currently trying to add an post page on my Wordpress website. I put my new post page as the default post page, on Settings -> Reading.

The id of my page is 353. So I created a new php file named `page-353.php` based on `page.php`. But the current template is still `index.php`.

Is there a way I can customize the HTML/PHP of the default post page?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, since I found the solution: this page have a default name, since it's a key page for Wordpress. Considering [this chart](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png) its name is `home.php`.